# Problems with require and a html file

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to require a html template file as part of my KnockoutJS component registration. According to Chrome's network tab, all the other files load fine except login-template.html which appears as

```
file:///home/leon/Dev/KnockOutJS/Component%20Example/js/lib/text.js
```

in my local file path. What Am I doing wrong here?

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        jquery: 'jquery-3.3.1',
        knockout: 'knockout-3.4.2',
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'knockout', 'app/login-component', 'text!app/login-template.html'],
function ($, ko, loginComponent, loginTemplate) {

    ko.components.register('login-component', {
        viewModel: { require: loginComponent },
        template: { require: loginTemplate }
    });

    ko.applyBindings();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the text plugin from https://github.com/requirejs/text